# Woocommerce rest api authentication & changes to default htaccess block

Tags: wordpress, api, .htaccess, woocommerce, authorization

whenever an update runs on the site, our edited block (below) changes back to the default, which breaks authentication.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

aside from tracking down a plugin that changes this, is there anything else you'd recommend i look into? is there anything i can do to stop this block changing?
if you need more info to provide any direction - please just let me know.
many thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

You should not make any changes between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` - that is the part that WP will *overwrite* when any changes are made to the permalink settings.

Try and place your own stuff before it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
...
```